# can't find variable navigation in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation

when i run it in expo it says "can't find variable navigation" , I can't seem to figure out why navigation isn't working does anyone have any ideas? I've tried taking this.props away etc but that doesn't work either

```
'use strict'
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
  StatusBar,
  ListView,
  FlatList,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import firebaseApp from './firebaseConfig.js';
import styles from './styles.js';

class Rooms extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Rooms',
    header: null
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var firebaseDB = firebaseApp.database();
    this.roomsRef = firebaseDB.ref('rooms');
    this.state = {
      rooms: [],
      newRoom: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.listenForRooms(this.roomsRef);
  }

  listenForRooms(roomsRef) {
    roomsRef.on('value', (dataSnapshot) => {
      var roomsFB = [];
      dataSnapshot.forEach((child) => {
        roomsFB.push({
          name: child.val().name,
          key: child.key
        });
      });
      this.setState({ rooms: roomsFB });
    });
  }

  addRoom() {
    if (this.state.newRoom === '') {
      return;
    }
    this.roomsRef.push({ name: this.state.newRoom });
    this.setState({ newRoom: '' });
  }

  openMessages(room) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Messages', {roomKey: room.key, roomName: room.name});
  }

  renderRow(item) {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight style={styles.roomLi}
      underlayColor="#fff"
      onPress={() => this.openMessages(item)}
      >
        <Text style={styles.roomLiText}>{item.name}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.roomsContainer}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"/>
        <Text style={styles.roomsHeader}>Chatypus</Text>
        <View style={styles.roomsInputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.roomsInput}
            placeholder={"New Room Name"}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({newRoom: text})}
            value={this.state.newRoom}
          />
          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.roomsNewButton}
            underlayColor="#fff"
            onPress={() => this.addRoom()}
          >
            <Text style={styles.roomsNewButtonText}>Create</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.roomsListContainer}>
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.rooms}
            renderItem={({item}) => (this.renderRow(item)
            )}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Rooms;
```

Comment: Which line is the code failing on? Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan hi im new to RN so im not sure how to see the trace, but when i run it on my phone, the error happens when i press on a chat so its the open message function i believe

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan hi Arun, i'm basically following this tutorial, the github repo of all the code is listed at the end https://medium.com/@_platypus_/react-native-chat-application-679dbff3ccd3 . Maybe I think its because I'm using expo to run my apps, as I've just used the rooms.js and message.js in my project, but i feel like it should still work so im not sure why

Comment: The article you linked is old and is using v1.0.0-beta.11 of `react-navigation` which is no longer maintained. I would recommend reading the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation) on how to set up react-navigation for the version you're using.

Comment: where do you setup your Rooms component inside your Navigator? Only defined screens gets the `navigation` prop injected automatically. You will need to manually pass the `navigation` prop for all other components